# Look through all files in ALL subfolders and retrieve data from one cell and paste on Master Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create something that would loop through all the files from a directory with subfolders. Then, it would open each excel file and copy the total amount. The cell that contains the total is not always in a specific row, but column B of that row contains the text " TOTAL AMOUNT". The cell that contains the total is ALWAYS in column I. After it copies the cell, paste in the Master workbook ( the workbook the macro is running from ) in a new sheet in cell (i,2)

Cell(1,1) and Cell(1,2) are headers. "GROUPER" and "EFT_AMOUNT"

Here is what I have so far :

```
Sub PaymentFileMatching()


    Dim HostFolder As String
    Dim f As String, i As Long, arr, sht As Worksheet
    Dim FSO As Object, objFolder As Object, FileInFolder As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook, Masterwb As Workbook
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")

    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    HostFolder = "C:\Users\kxc8574\Documents\Payment Files\Payment Files (Corrected)\PE20170701\"
    Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(HostFolder)
    Set Masterwb = Workbooks("Master Template")
    Sheets("Sheet9").Activate
    sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = _
                Array("GROUPER", "EFT_AMOUNT")
    i = 2
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        For Each FileInFolder In objSubFolder.Files
            sht.Cells(i, 1).Value = Left(FileInFolder.Name, InStr(FileInFolder.Name, "PE 2017") - 1)
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(objSubFolder & "\" & FileInFolder.Name)
                For Each sht In Worksheets
                    For Each Cell In Sheets("Payment Summary").Range("B:B")
                        If Cell.Value = "Final EFT Payment Amount" Then
                            matchRow = Cell.Row
                            Cells(matchRow, 8).Copy
                            Workbooks("Master Template").Worksheets("Sheet9").Cells(i, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                            i = i + 1
                        End If
                    Next Cell



        Next FileInFolder
    Next objSubFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: It would not go past cell.value = "final EFT payment amount ".. not sure if it's a syntax problem... sorry, I am still new to VBA

Answer (score 0):

You arent defining what `Cell` is - put `Option Explicit` at the very top of your module and then try compiling and it will tell you the things you forgot to define. To define  it use

`Dim Cell as Range`

Comment: `For Each Cell In Sheets("Payment Summary").Range("B:B")` appears in the original code, which is in implicit declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub PaymentFileMatching()


    Const HostFolder As String = _
             "C:\Users\kxc8574\Documents\Payment Files\Payment Files (Corrected)\PE20170701\"

    Dim i As Long
    Dim FSO As Object, objFolder As Object, FileInFolder As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook, Masterwb As Workbook, MasterSht As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
    Dim objSubFolder As Object, f As Range, fName As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(HostFolder)

    Set Masterwb = Workbooks("Master Template")
    Set MasterSht = Masterwb.Sheets("Sheet9")

    MasterSht.Activate
    MasterSht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array("GROUPER", "EFT_AMOUNT")

    i = 2
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        For Each FileInFolder In objSubFolder.Files

            fName = FileInFolder.Name
            MasterSht.Cells(i, 1).Value = Left(fName, InStr(fName, "PE 2017") - 1)

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(objSubFolder & "\" & fName)

            For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
                Set f = sht.Columns(2).Find("Final EFT Payment Amount", , xlValues, xlWhole)
                If Not f Is Nothing Then
                    MasterSht.Cells(i, 2).Value = f.EntireRow.Cells(8).Value
                    i = i + 1
                    Exit For 'found the value...
                End If
                Set f = Nothing
            Next sht

            wb.Close False

        Next FileInFolder
    Next objSubFolder

End Sub
```